# Ansible loop values using with_list with multiple variables

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create list of users using different variables in same code as list of variables.

The variables i have defined as below:

```
org1:
  - { name: 'Sales',         id: "{{ 'john,mike'.split(',') }}"}

org2:
  - { name: 'Testing',       id: "{{ 'samy,jazz'.split(',') }}"}
  - { name: 'dept303',       id: "{{ 'doug'.split(',') }}"}
```

The code i have written as below. This code is working while i am using single variable.

```
- name: Create users entry
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/vsftpd_users/user_list"
    line: "{{ item.1 | lower }}"
  with_list: "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

but not working while trying to use as list. It creates a long junk line with all converted values.

```
with_list:
- "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"
- "{{ lookup('subelements', org2, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Is there any other way to do so? or i am missing something here. Please help me me out here. Thank you.

> My Ansible version: ansible 2.2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making lists of lists.  If you just did

```
with_lists:
- "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

you would still have the same issue.

What you want to do is concatenate them together

```
with_lists: "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) + 
                lookup('subelements', org2, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not working. `with_list: "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) }} + {{ lookup('subelements', org2, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"`.  While doing so, I get only "(" as output.

Comment: My bad.  I had 2 extra { on the second line.  I have updated my answer to remove them.

Comment: While "{" removed, it looks now `with_list: "{{ lookup('subelements', org1, 'id', skip_missing=True) + lookup('subelements', org2, 'id', skip_missing=True) }}"` that has error throwing by ansible. `{"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred: can only concatenate list (not \"tuple\") to list"}`

Comment: Hmm.  I'm using Ansible 2.5.1.  I wonder if that was an update made in a version of Ansible that is newer than yours.  If so, you can debug what {{ item }} contains and then update to access the correct element in what your version of Ansible gives you.  If you can upgrade your version of Ansible, even better.

Comment: You were correct @Lewis. Found the issue now. While executing, for Org1 there are only single entry in the example, that caused creating junc. While added another line, it worked well. I dont know the logic behind this, but thats how my issue got fixed.